# How to read and write server files in dart

Tags: dart

I'm writing a dart based application. I want to read from and write to a server side file. Every read operation should read the last line of the file and the write operations should write to the end of the file. How would I do this?

To give a better idea, in Python I'd do it as:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.readline()
    f.write('baz')
```

UPDATE: This is a browser based Dart app. Apparently dart:io does not work with browser-based apps.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
import 'dart:io';

readLastLine(File f) => f.readAsLinesSync().last;
append(File f, String contents) =>
    f.writeAsStringSync(contents, mode: FileMode.APPEND);
```

NB: UTF8 is used as default encoding. You can change it with the optional named parameter `encoding` on `readAsLinesSync` and `writeAsStringSync`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it out

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing in the problem specification. I'm creating a browser-based app using Dart. I just came to know that the dart:io library does not work with browser based apps. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You can't read/write files from code that runs inside the browser. What you need is a server that does the file read/write (can be written in Dart) and your browser application connects to the server with HTTP requests to send commands and data for the server to interpret which then return results.